# In Excel, how do I handle someone else's workbook that uses UNICODE?

Tags: microsoft-excel, unicode

I have been sent an Excel workbook in which I find that a cell that appears to contain the letter "A" produces FALSE if I compare it with "A". That is, if the cell in question were B2 then =B2="A" returns FALSE.

In trying to figure it out, I noticed the following:

```
=CODE("A") returns 65
and 
=UNICODE("A") returns 65
```

and, assuming I've typed an "A" into a hitherto empty cell -- C3 say:

```
=CODE(C3) returns 65
and 
=UNICODE(C3) returns 65
```

All as expected.

HOWEVER, by contrast -- and, again, assume B2 is the pre-existing cell that appears to contain an "A" -- I notice the following:

```
=CODE(B2) returns 63 (question mark??)
and 
=UNICODE(B2) returns 1040
```

My understanding is that UNICODE 1040 is a "Cyrillic A", and I'm not sure if it's related but the author of the spreadsheet is in Serbia (while I am in the US).

Now I'd really like to have things that look, swim, and quack like any given letter, to actually *be* that letter.

**So, what us going on, and how do I fix it?**

Comment: Try saving a copy of the spreadsheet as UTF-8: https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-change-encoding-in-excel/ and  https://help.alchemer.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16 . Of course, if saved to CSV, formulas will no longer work,...

Comment: This is a known Issue with Unicode , with no Solution. Depends on what you want to be Equal & what you want to be not Equal. Even "looking same" is not a valid way to check , because the font used may make it look almost same , while some other font may make it look Entirely Different. [Cont] +

Comment: + [Cont] The Best you can try is to make your Custom function to check for Equality , where you can Extract Character-by-Character , check whether those two belong to the same set (which you have to list out) , then return true when all are matching. Eg your sets may be like [ (A,А,А́,А̀,А̂,А̄,Ӓ) , (E,Е,Е́,Ѐ,Е̄,Е̂,Ё) , (I,І,І́,Ї,Ї́) , (O,О,О́,О̀,О̂,Ō,Ӧ) ] , which is just the Cyrillic variations. Somebody else may want some other sets , hence there is no Universal Solution.